# NSPredicate to call relationships

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, mapkit

I currently have my core data model set up this way.

[image]

I currently use a fetchedResultController as well, I've tried using NSPredicate to compare values with a passed in coordinate. I've tried:

```
var location: Location!

func setUpFetchedResultsViewController() {
           let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<FlickrImage> = FlickrImage.fetchRequest()
           let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "latitude", ascending: true)
        let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "locations.latitude == %@", location.latitude)
        fetchRequest.predicate = predicate
           fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]
        fetchResultController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: dataController.viewContext, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)
        
           
           fetchResultController.delegate = self
           do {
               try fetchResultController.performFetch()
           } catch {
               print(error.localizedDescription)
           }
       }
```

I've also tried:

```
 let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "locations == %@", location)
```

It's either I get an error 'EXC_BAD_ACCESS' or it returns an empty array.

Comment: Have you checked that location isn't equal to nil?

Comment: @rs7 I have checked and it's the same value as the coordinates passed from the first view controller.

Comment: How about to fetch the `Location`s with the given latitude and map the result array to its `flickrImage` relationship. Your code doesn't work because the `locations` relationship is a collection type.

Comment: @vadian I also got confused at first because of the naming, but locations isn't a collection type -- the double arrows are point to locations, not from locations. It's a many-to-one relationship. Also, it seems like he wants to fetch an object of type FlickrImage rather than an object of type Location.

Comment: @rs7 You're right, the naming is confusing.

Comment: @vadian Thank you both. When saving downloaded content, I saved locations as well as its coordinates and it worked. I also took note of how to check Core Data if its nil.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me, give it a shot:

```
func setUpFetchedResultsViewController() {
    let request: NSFetchRequest<FlickrImage> = FlickrImage.fetchRequest()
    request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "locations == %@", locations)
    request.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "latitude", ascending: true)]
    do {
        return try context.fetch(request)
    } catch {
        print("Error fetching data from context: \(error)")
    }
    return []
}
```

If you want to access latitude, you first need to check that locations isn't nil:

```
func setUpFetchedResultsViewController() {
    let request: NSFetchRequest<FlickrImage> = FlickrImage.fetchRequest()
    request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "locations != nil AND locations.latitude == %@", locations.latitude)
    request.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "latitude", ascending: true)]
    do {
        return try context.fetch(request)
    } catch {
        print("Error fetching data from context: \(error)")
    }
    return []
}
```

Also, consider changing locations to location since it's a to-one relationship.